# wpf binding of an observablecollection(of observablecollection(of double)) in a Datagrid

Tags: xml, wpf, vb.net, binding, datagrid

I am attempting to implement a datagrid with variable number of rows and columns which is bound to an ObservableCollection(of ObservableCollection(of Double)

I want to use this collection with the inner collection representing the values to appear in the row where the Outer collection contains the rows for the datagrid.  I also have an observablecollection(of string) which contains the set of column titles.

### Is there a way to bind the titles to the title collection and the data to the two dimensional array of data?

### | Title1 | Title2 | Title3 | Title4 |

|  11.00 |  20.00 |  45.00 | 100.00 |
|-----------------------------------------------
|   1.00 | 230.00 |        |        |
|-----------------------------------------------
 and so on...

My View model is as follows:

```
Public Class MainWindowViewModel
   Inherits ViewModelBase

   Private _dgvData As ObservableCollection(Of ObservableCollection(Of Double)) = New ObservableCollection(Of ObservableCollection(Of Double))()
   Private _dgvTitles As ObservableCollection(Of String)

   Public Property DgvData As ObservableCollection(Of ObservableCollection(Of Double))
      Get
         Return _dgvData
      End Get
      Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of ObservableCollection(Of Double)))
         _dgvData = value
         RaisePropertyChanged(Function() DgvData)
      End Set
   End Property
   Public Property DgvTitles As ObservableCollection(Of String)
      Get
         Return _dgvTitles
      End Get
      Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of String))
         _dgvTitles = value
         RaisePropertyChanged(Function() DgvTitles)
      End Set
   End Property

   Public Sub New()
      PopulateDatagrid()
   End Sub

   Public Sub PopulateDatagrid()
      Dim oc As ObservableCollection(Of ObservableCollection(Of Double)) = New ObservableCollection(Of ObservableCollection(Of Double))()
      Dim row As ObservableCollection(Of Double) = New ObservableCollection(Of Double)()
      row.Add(11D)
      row.Add(20D)
      row.Add(45D)
      row.Add(100D)
      oc.Add(row)
      DgvData = New ObservableCollection(Of ObservableCollection(Of Double))(oc)

      Dim tc As ObservableCollection(Of String) = New ObservableCollection(Of String)()
      tc.Add("One")
      tc.Add("Two")
      tc.Add("Three")
      tc.Add("Four")
      DgvTitles = New ObservableCollection(Of String)(tc)
   End Sub
End Class
```

My Form is as follows:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TwoDimBindingProblem"
        Title="MainWindow"
        >

   <Window.DataContext>
      <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
   </Window.DataContext>
   <Grid>
      <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  Orientation="Vertical">
         <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DgvData}"
                   ColumnWidth="*"
                   CanUserAddRows="False"
                   AutoGenerateColumns="True">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
               <local:BindingProxy x:Key="BindingProxy" Data="{Binding}"/>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
               <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding DgvTitles}"/>
                  </DataTemplate>
               </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
         </DataGrid>
      </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

All I get is a window that looks like this.  Any ideas on how to bind the collection of titles to the column headers as well as the two dimensional observablecollection to the datagrid?

[Output WPF Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGg53.jpg)

Comment: You need to bind to something stable, a collection of doubles is not only unstable but it does not have any properties for you to bind to. What you might want to think about is a custom class that has more `Public Property Field1 as Double` properties than you will ever need. Then fill in your outer collection with these filled in and bind to those. The only other way would be to dynamically build a datatable with columns for the max number of columns you have in your data and then bind to that.

Comment: Thanks Steve.  I think I'll take the approach of a class with lots of property values.  I think the maximum I'll ever need is twenty, so it should be a relatively easy thing from there.

Comment: Anybody know how to bind a datagrid column titles to a collection of strings?